# R: How to create result table of the results of multiple statistics tests?

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, chi-squared

I am a complete beginner in R.

I ran multiple Chi-square tests on a column of data in R with this code:

```
apply(mydata, 2, chisq.test, p=expected.probability)
```

and got multiple results like this:

> $`Primary Tumor`
>
> Chi-squared test for given probabilities
>
> data:  newX[, i] X-squared = 515108, df = 6, p-value < 2.2e-16
>
> $`Primary Tumor_1`
>
> Chi-squared test for given probabilities
>
> data:  newX[, i] X-squared = 583205, df = 6, p-value < 2.2e-16
>
> $`Primary Tumor_2`
>
> Chi-squared test for given probabilities
>
> data:  newX[, i] X-squared = 58089, df = 6, p-value < 2.2e-16

Can extract a results table with Tumour number, x-squared results, df and p-value of 50 samples I tested?

I can copy and paste in excel but I wanna learn code for larger sample.

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see are the names of the chisq test:

```
names(chisq.test(matrix(1:4,ncol=2)))
[1] "statistic" "parameter" "p.value"   "method"    "data.name" "observed" 
[7] "expected"  "residuals" "stdres"
```

The values you need are statistic (chisq), parameter (df), p.value.

So we simulate data:

```
mydata = matrix(rpois(100,50),ncol=10)
colnames(mydata) = paste0("tumor",1:10)
```

And write a more elaborate function to take out these parameters after the test

```
res = apply(mydata,2,function(x){
chisq.test(x,p=rep(0.1,10))[c("statistic","parameter","p.value")]
})
```

And we make it a data.frame:

```
df = data.frame(id=names(res),do.call(rbind,res))
df

             id statistic parameter   p.value
tumor1   tumor1  4.322896         9 0.8889048
tumor2   tumor2  5.285714         9 0.8087245
tumor3   tumor3  2.803063         9 0.9715936
tumor4   tumor4   8.62578         9 0.4725097
tumor5   tumor5  13.22846         9 0.1525381
tumor6   tumor6  8.653768         9 0.4698283
tumor7   tumor7  7.666667         9 0.5680554
tumor8   tumor8  5.919132         9 0.7479838
tumor9   tumor9  8.051335         9 0.5289813
tumor10 tumor10  13.46875         9 0.1425173
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! It really helped:)

Comment: Can I ask further question? I ran Chi-squared test for 50 samples, does this mean that I have to use adjusted p-values such as FDR instead of p-value to correct for multiple tests?

Comment: No problem :) Yes in theory you should. Using my example above, you can do p.adjust(df$p.value,"BH"). BH means benjamini hochberg correction. Let me know if you have similar problems along this line

Comment: Where should I put p.adjust(df$p.value,"BH")? Instead of normal p value? I tried 'test <-p.adjust(res$p.value,"BH")' but it didn't work. It gives 'numeric(0)'.. Sorry for such a basic question...!

Comment: Hi @KimSoYon, using the example above, the results should be in df; so you do df$padj = p.adjust(df$p.value,"BH") ; and the adjusted p value is in the table

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df <- apply(mydata, 2, chisq.test, p=expected.probability)
```

just assigns it to a variable that can be accessed from your environment... check this question out too it may help you as well. [chi square test for each row in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192828/chi-square-test-for-each-row-in-data-frame)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got it now:)

Comment: accept answers that are correct so others can see as well :)